# Circuitikz - draw a pmos with with empty circle

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to draw a pmos symbol, with an empty (white) circle. According to the CircuiTikZ manual you an do that with either: adding `emptypmoscircle` as a parameter in the `usepackage` command, adding `emptycircle` as a parameter in the pmos node, or adding `\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos style/emptycircle}` in the preamble. Neither of those have worked for me, anyone has any idea?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[emptypmoscircle]{circuitikz} (doesn't work)
\usepackage{circuitikz}

%\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos style/emptycircle} (doesn't work)

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw 
%(0,0) node[pmos, emptycircle] {}; (doesn't work)
(0,0) node[pmos] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Compiling locally (v0.7) all three possible ways to generate the empty circle you give work.  Moving to Overleaf (v0.4) nothing works, most likely you need to update your version of CircuiTikZ (you can find the version on your current system by looking through the `.log` file).

Comment: You are right, I'm using version 0.4, that should do the trick, thank you! I'll try later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by using an old version.

Comment: It worked! ;)..